# Android ProgressDialog Resizes by it self

Tags: android, progressdialog

I am removing some extra files from sd card
Here is the ProgressDialog
[image]

the problem is that when file name gets long it goes to 2nd line and dialog's size increases and when file name is short is goes to 1 line and size of dialog decreases , so because of this its size increase and decrease randomly ...
i have tried this

```
progressDialog.show();
Window window = progressDialog.getWindow();
window.setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

but it only increases the width of dialog.. i want the size of dialog reamin constant.. how can i do this..?

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ListHomeActivity.this);
progressDialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.updates));
progressDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.msg_download));
progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
progressDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, getResources().getString(R.string.lbl_Cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
            {               
                if(new File(Common.XLEZInput_Client_PATH).exists())
                {
                    // delete download folder.              
                    globalMethods.deleteSubFolder(new File(Common.XLEZInput_Download_PATH));
                }
                checkForUpdatesTask.cancel(true);
            }
        });
        progressDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting hard coded values. Like:
progressDialog.show();
Window window = progressDialog.getWindow();
window.setLayout(200, 170);

Comment: this basically changes the width and place of dialog on screen.. my problem is with the height of dialog...

Comment: You can have one simple solution..
Keep a standard text length in characters..e.g 100..if the text lenght is smaller than 100, than add spaces at the eng of the text upto 100..in this way all the textwill have 100 characters exact..and the progress size will always be same